# REACT ¿Como llenar un Array que esta dentro de otro con React.useState()?

Tags: reactjs, post, usestate

Estoy tratando de registrar un "profesor" el cual puede tener varios "cursos". desde mi backend espero una estructura de este tipo:

```
    "nombre": "yony meza",
    "titulo": "ingeniero en sistemas",
    "experiencia": 15,
    "cursos": [
      {
        "idcurso":1        
      },
      {
        "idcurso":2        
      }   
    ]
}
```

Definí un arreglo profesor y el cual pretendo llenar con la función setProfesor

```
    const [profesor, setProfesor] = React.useState({
        nombre: "",
        titulo: "",
        experiencia: "",
        cursos : []
    })
```

Cree este formulario donde pretendo obtener los datos **nombre**, **titulo** y **experiencia** con las siguientes funciones

```
const onInputChange = e => {
        setProfesor({...profesor, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
```

[image: Formulario desde donde cargo los datos del profesor y tomo el id de los cursos que tenga a cargo]

ademas tengo la siguiente función para cuando se da click en *añadir* con la que voy recogiendo los id de los cursos seleccionados:

```
const addCursoelegido = (id) => {
    const registro = {"idcurso": id};
       setProfesor({cursos: [...profesor.cursos, registro]});
    }
```

Una vez tengo los datos necesarios para crear el profesor. tengo la siguiente función para hacer el correspondiente registro en la base de datos.

```
const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(profesor);
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/profesor", profesor);
        setProfesor({nombre: "", titulo: "", experiencia: "", cursos: []})
        navigate("/profesores");
    }
```

Cuando estoy llenando el formulario desde el navegador parece como si la estructura creada por el state fuera la correcta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo al momento de enviar el POST cuando le doy click en *registrar* no se genera nada y viendo el error en consola noto que la estructura que se envía no es en realidad correcta.

[image: impresion en consola del objeto profesor que se envia al tratar de hacer el POST]

No tengo experiencia en el uso de react y se que mi backend esta bien porque ya lo he testeado desde postman con el set que puse al principio y funciona perfectamente.
Seria de mucha de ayuda si pueden guiarme en como debo generar esta estructura de manera correcta para no tener problema al momento de hacer el registro.

Por ultimo incluyo toda la clase AddProfesor.js completa:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


export default function AddProfesor() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [cursoslist, setCu] = React.useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
       loadCursos();
    }, []);

    const loadCursos = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/cursos");
        setCu(result.data.reverse());
    }
    
    const [profesor, setProfesor] = React.useState({
        nombre: "",
        titulo: "",
        experiencia: "",
        cursos : []
    })

    const {nombre, titulo, experiencia} = profesor;
    
    const addCursoelegido = (id) => {
    const registro = {"idcurso": id};
       setProfesor({cursos: [...profesor.cursos, registro]});
    }
    
    const onInputChange = e => {
        setProfesor({...profesor, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    
    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(profesor);
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/profesor", profesor);
        setProfesor({nombre: "", titulo: "", experiencia: "", cursos: []})
        navigate("/profesores");
    }

    
    return (
        <div className = "container">
            <div className = "row">
                <div className = "col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow">
                    <h1 className = "text-center">Registrar nuevo Profesor</h1>
                    <form onSubmit = {e => onSubmit(e)}>
                    
                        <div className='mb-3'>
                            <label htmlFor='nombre' className='form-label'>
                                Nombre
                            </label>
                            <input 
                                type={'text'} 
                                className='form-control' 
                                name='nombre'
                                placeholder='Ingrese el nombre del profesor'
                                value={nombre}
                                onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div className='mb-3'>
                            <label htmlFor='Titulo' className='form-label'>
                                Maximo titulo academico
                            </label>
                            <input 
                                type={'text'} 
                                className='form-control' 
                                name='titulo'
                                placeholder='Ingrese el titulo academico del profesor' 
                                value={titulo}
                                onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div className='mb-3'>
                            <label htmlFor='experiencia' className='form-label'>
                                Años de experiencia
                            </label>
                            <input 
                                type={'integer'} 
                                className='form-control' 
                                name='experiencia'
                                placeholder='Ingrese los años de experiencia del profesor'
                                value={experiencia}
                                onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                                />
                        </div>
                        
                        <button type='submit' className = "btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
                        <Link className = "btn btn-danger mx-2" to={"/"}>Cancelar</Link>
                    </form>
                    <div className="py-4">
            <table className="table border shadow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">PreRequisito</th>
                    <th scope="col">#Creditos</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cupos</th>
                    <th scope="col">Accion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        cursoslist.map((curso, index) => (
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                                <td>{curso.nombre}</td>
                                <td>{curso.requisito}</td>
                                <td>{curso.creditos}</td>
                                <td>{curso.cupos}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button 
                                    className="btn btn-danger"
                                    onClick={() => addCursoelegido(curso.id)}
                                    >Añadir
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))


                    }
                    
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        
        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo ya encontré el problema,

```
const addCursoelegido = (id) => {
  let registro = { idcurso: id };
  let nuevoProfesor = { ...profesor };
  let newcursos = nuevoProfesor.cursos.concat(registro);

  setProfesor({ ...profesor, cursos: newcursos });
};
```

Modificando así tu componente obtengo el resultado que necesitas en mi backend.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta acabo de notar que en realidad lo que me falta es asignarle una "entidad" en este caso profesor.
{
profesor:{
    "nombre": "yony meza",
    "titulo": "ingeniero en sistemas",
    "experiencia": 15,
    "cursos": [
      {
        "idcurso":1        
      },
      {
        "idcurso":2        
      }   
    ]
}
}